# JSON Exception Handling Syntax unclear to me -- JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, django, django-views

I am using JSON to get some data from an API and if the entered URL is wrong(which is very possible) the JSON file returns: "Unknown symbol"

The error message is as follows : (don't be scared a lot of it is just relevant information, scroll down to the bottom I have **highlighted the main error**.)

```
Environment:



Request Method: POST

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/buy/



Django Version: 3.1.2

Python Version: 3.7.0

Installed Applications:

['django.contrib.admin',

'django.contrib.auth',

'django.contrib.contenttypes',

'django.contrib.sessions',

'django.contrib.messages',

'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'accounts']

Installed Middleware:

['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',

'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']







Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode

obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)



During handling of the above exception (0), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner

response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response

response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view

return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\Desktop\python websites\trading_website\accounts\views.py", line 116, in buy

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json

return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads

return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode

obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "C:\Users\VARDHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None



**Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /buy/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**
```

The fix I tried :

```
try:
    ....
               
except JSONDecodeError:
                       messages.error(request, "The is ticker is either wrong or not supported. Please try another one :)")
                       return redirect ("buy")
```

Comment: maybe `json_data` not right format. Try check it first

Comment: oh, it is just a variable for "json_data = requests.get(url).json()" and it handles the cases with proper data properly, I just can't figure out how to deal with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling an API, there are chances that your API call fails and returns just string or empty response. I would suggest that you first add a check on the status code of your response something like below  and then process the json data.

```
    data = requests.get(url)
    if data.status != 200:
        raise Exception("Error") 
   json_data = data.json()
```

Comment: Hello fellow human,

Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it! Like honestly I respect your time and really appreciate the fact that you gave some of it to help someone else! that tell me you are a good person

I had some errors with this solution but I finally sussed it out, I couldn't figure out the HTTP module that you had used, nevertheless, that gave me an idea and I used this:

this works like a charm and I honestly couldn't have gotten this without your help!

I spent all my morning trying to figure this out and now that I finally have it feels awesomeeeeeeeee!

Comment: and btw, the syntax for "data.status" is now changed to  "data.status_code" please beware of that, thanks for the help!